# Paying taxes revenue vs taxes profit

Tags: taxes

Regarding taxes, why do people pay taxes on their revenue and companies pay taxes on their profit?

Comment: Can you explain/clarify what you mean? Ultimately the answer is likely to be "because that's how the tax code in [whatever jurisdiction] says taxes work"

Comment: How do you define "profit" for an individual and how is it different from income minus deductions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot more variation in expenses between businesses with the same revenue than there is between individuals at the same income level.  And most individual expenditures are done not for the purpose of making money but for the purpose of consumption.

If you look across different types of businesses, there is a huge variation in the profit margin (the percentage of revenue that ends up as profit).  A typical grocery store, for example, has a [profit margin of between 1 and 3 percent](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/profit-margin-supermarket-22467.html).  It generates quite a bit of revenue but almost all of that revenue has to go to buying products to put on shelves, paying people to stock the shelves, paying to rent the store, etc.  Apple, on the other hand, has a [profit margin of 38-40%](https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AAPL/explorer/gp_margin#:~:text=Apple's%20latest%20twelve%20months%20gross,ending%20September%202015%20to%202019.).

If you applied a tax on revenue of, say, 4%, you'd immediately make every grocery store unprofitable unless they immediately increased their prices by a bit more than 4%.  And the government would be making more from every grocery store than the store's owners.  That would also be very expensive for consumers since groceries and other purchases from low margin businesses are a large fraction of the budget of most low- and middle-income consumers.  On the other hand, that same 4% tax on revenue would be roughly 10% of Apple's profits.  If you're going to tax corporations, it makes much more sense to set the rate based on profits so that it is closer to fair across different types of businesses.

If you look at individuals earning the same gross income, there is much less variation in the amount of that income that goes to necessities vs luxuries (the closest thing to a business's expenses and profits).  Sure, there are differences-- a $100k salary in Silicon Valley doesn't go as far as it does in rural Arkansas-- but the differences aren't generally as stark as they are for businesses.  And it is much easier to identify the expenses for a business than to figure out what an individual's necessities are.  Clearly, everyone needs shelter but does the individual need a single-family home in a pricey neighborhood or would a studio apartment 2 tows over be enough.  Where there are large differences-- some people have large bills for medical conditions or specialized care that others don't-- the tax code generally allows individuals to deduct those expenses in order to be more fair.

Businesses also pay expenses (presumably) for the purpose of making profits.  It is highly unlikely that a business is going to incur a huge expense just "for fun" with no expectation that it is going to generate more revenue from that expense.  Even where the company is making expenditures to make employees happier (free or subsidized lunches, business class airfare for travelers, etc.), those expenses are incurred with the intent that it makes employees more productive and the business more profitable.  Individuals pay expenses both in order to be able to make money and because they want to enjoy consuming the fruits of their labor.  No one bases their vacation budget on the amount of additional money they expect to make from being more relaxed or more well-traveled.  If they did, no one would go to Disney World.  People go there to enjoy themselves and have fun as a reward for hard work throughout the year.

Comment: Nice answer. Insightful first paragraph.